# What action should my Contact Form have, I am using Angular Routing to get contact.html

Tags: php, html, angularjs, email, routes

I am creating a personal website and I am using Angular JS routing for fast loading. I have a contact link on navbar and once a visitor clicks it. I load the code in contact.html inside index.html.

contact.html code contains PHP code and a HTML form. In this part of code I am using mail() for sending a email to myself once the form is filled by visitor.

When visitor clicks submit button, with incorrect information or incomplete data, the page is suppose to store the data user provided in those input fields and give errors. Contact.html works perfectly fine when I run it by itself on local server.

But when I go to index.html and then click on contact link, contact.html doesn't work as expected. Whenever submit is clicked with incorrect or incomplete data, it reloads the entire contact.html inside index.html instead of throwing errors and storing the previously filled information, as it is suppose to do.

How to make it work properly?

Here is my code

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'asfsa'; 
        $to = 'gabanimillin@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Millin Gab site ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

        // If there are no errors, send the email
        if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
      }
    }
  ?>

  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message">
          <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?>
        </textarea>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <?php echo $result; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Approach of doing all this templating in php is not taking advantage of using angular to do all of that for you. Think of your php as nothing but a data API that is used to send json to angular to do all the data binding to html files. You would have no `action` in the form and would bind one object to your form. When ready to submit ... angular would then send that object using `$http` as an ajax request

Comment: I am fairly new to javascript and I don't have much experience with angular. Can you please elaborate a bit more on your suggestion, so a newbie can understand.